# how to forget multiple cache keys with laravel 9 with default cache driver

Tags: laravel, caching

I have this controller with many functions and cache keys depending on the username....

I need when updating the information and delete all cache keys for a specific user? is there any way to do that?

my controller to get data from caches:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    private $cache_duration = 60*60*72;

    function home($uname) {
        $info =  Cache::remember('get-all-info-home'.$uname, $this->cache_duration, function() use($uname){
            $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->firstOrFail();
            return $user !=null ? $user->about : null;
        });
        return view('home', compact('info'));
    }


    function info($uname) {

        $info =  Cache::remember('get-all-info'.$uname, $this->cache_duration, function() use($uname){
            $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->firstOrFail();
            return $user !=null ? $user->about : null;
        });
        return view('info', compact(['info']));
    }

    function skills($uname) {
        $info =  Cache::remember('get-all-user-skills'.$uname, $this->cache_duration, function() use($uname){
            $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->firstOrFail();
            return $user !=null ? $user->about : null;
        });
        $skills =   Cache::remember('get-all-skills'.$uname, $this->cache_duration, function() use($uname){
            $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->firstOrFail();
            return $user !=null ? $user->skills : null;
        });

        return view('skills', compact(['skills', 'info']));
    }
```

I have tried this way, but still not working:

```
$uname = $info->user->name;
  $keys = ['get-all-info-home', 'get-all-info', 'get-all-user-skills',
             'get-all-skills', 'get-all-user-users-education-experiences', 'get-all-education',
             'get-all-experiences', 'get-all-user-users-user-achievements', 'get-all-user-users-achievements',
            'get-all-user-users-user-services', 'get-all-user-users-services-unique',
             'get-all-user-users-user-services'];
             foreach($keys as $key) {
                $key = $key.$uname;
                Cache::forget($key);
             }
```

Comment: you could use a cache driver that supports 'tags' instead, then you could tag these cache values with an identifier for the user then you could clear all of that tag (invalidating all the cache keys for that user) ... or you can just keep a list of the prefix for each of the cache keys you want to invalidate `['get-all-info-home', 'get-all-info', ...]` then spin through those appending the `$uname` and forgetting it

Comment: i try this but doesn't work!, i updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what lagbox mentioned, change to memcache or redis driver that supports tags, and add

```
Cache::

to

Cache::tags('user.....
```

in your controller method:

```
    function home($uname) {
        $info =  Cache::tags('user'.$uname)
            ->remember('get-all-info-home'.$uname, $this->cache_duration, function() use($uname){
            $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->firstOrFail();
            return $user !=null ? $user->about : null;
        });
        return view('home', compact('info'));
    }

    function info($uname) {

        $info =  Cache::tags('user'.$uname)
->remember('get-all-info'.$uname, $this->cache_duration, function() use($uname){
            $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->firstOrFail();
            return $user !=null ? $user->about : null;
        });
        return view('info', compact(['info']));
    }
```

```
then for the cache tag clear you would do:
```

```
Cache::tags('user'.$info->user->name)->flush()
```

if adding tagging is not not feasible for any reason, try checking and making sure that the $key.uname is actually returning the data you are expecting

```
            foreach($keys as $key) {
                $key = $key.$uname; // <- maybe this is not returning the right data
                dd($key);  // echo this out just to see if it is
                Cache::forget($key);
             }
```

Comment: Thanks, i had a problem with the place of my foreach loop, now it is working, but for tag, I think I cannot use it since I have used the default driver which is file for store caching